# How to get the html output of a python dash html component

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, pyfpdf

I want to convert my Plotly Dash web app to a pdf that is downloadable when a user clicks a button.

I'm searching for a `.toString()` type of function that will act on something like `html.Div()` to give me the string `<div>...</div>`.

This is so I can use the python package `fpdf` to write the web page to a pdf such as shown [here](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/HTML.html).

I've had a look around the Dash documentation but can't find what I'm looking for, hoping I don't have to dive into the render pipeline.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do this for a given component, though you can export the whole figure html : `fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")`.